# filter XML elements and edit their values, ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

I want to filter my code based on id xmlelement value,based throught a QueryString, but it doesn't seem to be working!!!

```
XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
xdoc.Load(filepath);

XmlNode root = xdoc.DocumentElement;
XmlNode idNode = root.SelectSingleNode("/students/student/id");

           if (idNode.Value == null){create a new xml node}
else if (idNode.Value != null) {update the xml element with the value of id)
```

i tried to explain it in question, here is the link...

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13607387/edit-xml-elements-of-a-specific-node-based-on-its-id-element-asp-net-page

Comment: Define not working. What is the specific error you are facing?

Comment: Please split your question into separate ones and explain what you can't implement. I.e. "how to select Xml node baed on value of 'id' element", "how to create XML node",... (your previous one was likley not got replies due to huge amount of code in it...)

Comment: when i want to create a new xml node,,, it doesnt create a new XML node...

Comment: it doesnt update xml nodes as well...

Comment: Do you have any real need to use `XmlDocument` rather than LINQ to XML? The latter is *much* nicer.

Comment: You haven't given the code you've *tried* to create a new node. What are you trying to *do* with the new node? Are you trying to add it to the document? Your question is currently very unclear.

Comment: yes i want to create a new xml node, and add it to the document...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to add student element, if there is no student for specified id (and possibly add some data to student node). Here is Linq to xml solution:

```
int id = 2;
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(filepath);
XElement student = xdoc.Descendants("student")
        .Where(s => (int)s.Element("id") == id)
        .SingleOrDefault();

if (student == null)
{
    student = new XElement("student",
                        new XElement("id", id),
                        new XElement("first_name"),
                        new XElement("last_name")); // add other elements here
    xdoc.Root.Add(student);
}

student.Element("first_name").Value = TextBox_firstname.Text;
student.Element("last_name").Value = TextBox_lastname.Text;
// set other values here          

xdoc.Save(filepath);
```

Comment: I want to be able to edit the value of existing XML nodes based on their id (xml element) value, as well..

Comment: @user1750680 see update. If student do not exist in your xml, then you create student with provided id, and all other empty elements. Later you update student (it does not matter whether you found it by id, or added on previous step)

Comment: <students>
  <student>
    <id>1</id>
    <first_name>ahmad</first_name>
    <last_name>hani</last_name>
  </student>
</students>
this is my xml,,, how can i get the value id element to be able to put it in "student" element you created above...

Comment: @user1750680 id element added here `new XElement("id", id)` - it creates new element with name `<id>` and value of id, which you used for searching student

Comment: in Page_Load i assign queryString values to textboxes,,,
student.Element("first_name").Value = TextBox_firstname.Text;
doesn't save the user edited data (from textboxes) it saves the values of the queryString all over again in another node... how can i solve this..?

Comment: @user1750680 assign values from query string only if it is not post back

Comment: @user1750680 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.ispostback.aspx  If you will have further problems with retrieving text from text boxes, consider to ask new question on this problem